# Use concatenated fields in select input

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have 3 tables Books, Authors and books_authors.

In Authors there is a `firstname` and `lastname` field. In the `Author.php` entity, I have defined function `_getFullName()`, but as the documentation states:

> "Do bear in mind that virtual properties cannot be used in finds."

When I bake this and want to add a book, it in the BooksController function add creates:

```
$authors = $this->Books->Authors->find('list', ['limit' => 200,]);
```

to show a multiple select for the authors, but it only show the `author.id` in the select.

How do I get this to show the `full_name` in the select box?

Please only answer this, if the answer is for CakePHP version 3.

Comment: It's not that different from 2.x: **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#finding-key-value-pairs**

Comment: Thank you. In AuthorsTable.php I changed displayField to:
$this->displayField('full_name'); and it gave me the full name of the Authors.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you did wrong in table names the names should authors, books and authors_books.